# Loading a url into a div with jquery, how to post back to the div?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using the following to load a codeigniter view into a div, like an Iframe.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#divId').load('http://www.domain.oo/page.php?test=1);     
});
</script>
```

The div in my body

```
<div id="divId"></div>
```

The page post to the parent page when I hit submit in this div.
What should I do that it actually post using jquery and return the resulting page back into the div an don't refresh the parent page?

Comment: AJAX is your friend and wants to help.

Answer (score 0):

just use jquery.post

It will help to post the data without reloading page

$.post( "test.php", function( data ) {  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

```
         var url=  'http://www.domain.oo/page.php?test=1';
         $.ajax({
         url: url, success: function (data) 
                {
                        $('#divId').html(data);
                }
```

Here you can go back to previos page by back button(history)